# Joomla menu, destroys my template

Tags: joomla2.5, frontend, templating

Hello dear Stackers :)

I have been trying to migrate my new Joomla Template since this morning, it has take me this long to isolate the problem to the following few lines of code. 
The new company I work at does not have ftp access to their web servers, so we have to migrating via console :(

If I include this **menu** in the template, it will clear the whole page and return blank with no HTML other than:

```
<html>
    <head>
       <style type="text/css"></style></head>
    <body>
       <div id="menu_item" class="jjMenuItemDiv" style="display: none;">Copy without formatting</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The **menu** code I removed to make the rest work:

```
    <!-- Headder --> <!-- BUGG  ? -->
    <?php if ($this->countModules('main-menu')) : ?>
        <div class="header_wrapper">
            <div class="container ">
                <header class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 logo">
                        <a href="index.php">
                            <img src="images/Template/Logo/complit_logo_medium.png" height="100%" alt="complit logo" />
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-9 col-xs-6 menu">
                        <w:nav name="main-menu" />
                    </div>
                </header>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <!-- Service Menu --> <!-- BUGG  ? -->
    <?php if ($this->countModules('service-menu')) : ?>
    <div class="service_menu_wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <w:nav name="service-menu" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

**PHP Version 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.10**

**Joomla! 2.5.19**

Ideas on how/where to continue my bug-fixing would be greatly appreciated.

/ Az - A Joomla Newbie :)

Comment: The template works fine without the menu embedded :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: When I migrated the template from the testserver (not Ubuntu server) to the live server (Ubuntuserver), the menu configuration bugged hard. I do not have time to do a full check, but it works. A fresh joomla install on the Ubuntuserver and module-by-module migration made it work.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are hardcoding a menu into the template?? This is *not* how you should include a menu in Joomla.

Your index.php only needs to include something like:

```
<?php if($this->countModules('menu')) : ?>
    <nav role="navigation">
        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="menu" style="none" />
    </nav>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Then in Joomla's module manager you simply publish the menu module to a position called menu. Now your menu structure can be created using Joomla's menu manager.